# I am stuck in Grub screen after installing Fedora

Tags: fedora, grub

After installing Fedora on my laptop, i am stuck in the Grub screen.

**Here are my disk partitions**

[image: Disk partitions]

**I tried this**

```
grub> set root=(hd0,2)
grub> linux /vmlinuz-5.11.12-300.fc34x86
grub> initrd /initramfs-5.11.12-300.fc34.x86_65
grub> boot
```

**And got this error**
[image: Error after trying commands]

Am I using the wrong commands?
Could somebody tell me which commands I need to write.

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Good news, you made it far beyond grub. But: I assume you end up on the grub command line at all, because none of the set up boot menu entries work. is that correct?

Comment: @MarcusMüller correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you have three partitions:

- `gpt1` - EFI System
- `gpt2` - `/boot`
- `gpt3` - `/home` and `/root`

I don't think you've actually installed Fedora 'cause its files are nowhere to be seen. Alternatively you could have had a catastrophic FS corruption in which case I'd first run `badblocks` on this disk, check its `smartctl -a` status and then proceed to reinstall.

Comment: I reinstalled Fedora and its working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we are looking for the `/`, aka the "root" of the filesystem.  As opposed to `/root/` which is the "home directory" for `id 0`  which is usually directly under `/`, but may not be in your case.

You seem to believe the root filesystem is on `(hd0,2)`, did you mean to type `root=(hd0,gpt2)` ?

The root filesystem has `/bin /sbin /usr /etc /var`
so continue listing the files under each of those of those partitions until you find one with /bin and the like. eg:

```
ls (hd0,gpt3)/root/
ls (hd0,gpt2)/extlinux/
ls (hd0,gpt1)/System/
```

Consider the possibility of a failed filesystem or a failed drive.  Run a fsck on the ones you can see.

Was `/` encrypted before?